# perl test suite for API

Tags: perl, api, unit-testing, cpan, test-suite

I'm writing a [perl](http://www.perl.org) module that interfaces with an API and I would like to write a test suite for it before putting it up on [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org). However, because this module is basically just an interface for an API, all tests would require a valid API key and user. Obviously I can't release this module with my API key and username in the test suite, so what is the best way to handle something like this? Should I just test locally and then put it up on CPAN with no tests? Has anyone run into this before and come up with a good solution? I know that writing tests is best practice, so I'd like to do it if I can. Thanks!

Comment: You could write and deploy a fake api which doesn't need the key or a fake key to test the key mechanism. This could be swapped with the real api via an environment variable for people who have the real thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not wrap the API calls into small functions (e.g. the function does NOTHING but the API call), and then mock those functions in your tests as needed using `Test::MockObject` or similar?

This would be even better, as you would be able to have tests that test different results from API (failure, auth failure, etc...)

Comment: As a note: this is definitely a solution much more preferable to "skip the tests" one, but inferior to "mock the tests for unit testing 100% of non-API-call code + let the users supply their own key&user for integration test cases"

Comment: This answer is good too.  You'll get to test the bits that perform API return values.

Answer (score 3):

I made it clear in my documentation that my module was useless without an API key, and used skip:{} constructs of Test::More to skip all the tests if the key was not present.  You can choose too bail_out instead of skip.

Just insure that your docs explain how to communicate the API key to the module.

Comment: can you tell me the name of your module so I can look at it as an example?

Comment: yes. give me a minute to look it up.  I have not worked on it in over 2 years :-)

Comment: I wish to add that other than the CPAN Testing Service I can't imagine who needs to install an API wrapper module without an API key.

Comment: Thanks for the example! It's always useful to have working code that already does what you want :)

Comment: Note that my code also uses a myriad or ENV variable to determine which tests to run. That way if you don't have any objects of type B you don't make API calls to CRUD test them.

Comment: I have done the same thing: [`I22r-Translate`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MOB/I22r-Translate-0.94/t/)

Answer (score 2):

The usual way I handle this sort of thing is to require an environment variable in order to run the test suite. The environment variable will contain the useful bit of information (e.g. an API key, a hostname to connect to, etc.)

Here's an example of how you might handle this sort of thing from within a test file. We use this for the [MongoDB](https://metacpan.org/module/MongoDB) distribution to check if there's an available server to run against:

```
BEGIN {
    eval {
        my $host = exists $ENV{MONGOD} ? $ENV{MONGOD} : 'localhost';
        $conn = MongoDB::MongoClient->new( host => $host, ssl => $ENV{MONGO_SSL} );
    };

    if ( $@ ) {
        plan skip_all => $@;
        exit 0;
    }
};
```

All this does is try to connect to a host specified in the `MONGOD` environment variable (or else localhost.) If it can't, it skips all the tests and tells the reason why. The skips still count as a non-failure, so it won't prevent installation of the module if no test server is available.

I have this code in a .pm file which I `use` in every .t file in the distribution.